# Google Wallet Pass - Error 404 When adding to wallet

Tags: javascript, android-pay

I'm working through the [Google Passs Javascaript Tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-web#4). I already have a working pass generator using Java, and I'm just trying to translate that to a web based javascript project.

When I generate the url to add the pass to google wallet ([https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/[tokengoeshere]](https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/%5Btokengoeshere%5D)), it just gives me a generic error with a 404 code. I have no idea where to begin debugging. Am I missing a step? Is there an error with my request? I'm not getting any kind of more specific error to go off of. Any ideas where to look?

I've gone over both the authentication and request payload to generate the link - trying to make it match my working java project to no avail.

Comment: It's difficult to help you debug this without more information. A few possibilities that come to mind. Were you able to successfully sign the JWT with a service account key? Is the service account properly registered with the 'developer' role for your Wallet API account? If your account is still in 'demo mode' are you using the save to wallet link with a Google account that has either the 'administrator' or 'developer' role for your Wallet API account?